# shortest path from multiple Sets

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra, shortest-path

I have to find the shortest path beetween nodes in various sets, where I can use node only once from every set. Every node is connected via distance to every others nodes. There is exception where nodes in set are not connected between them. The path must contain one node from every set.

eg.

```
    Set A - [a1, a2, a3]
    Set B - [b1, b2]
    Set C - [c1]
    Set D - [d1, d2, d3]
    Set Z - [z1, z2, z3]
```

The nodes are a1,a2,a3,b1,b2...

eg.
The node **a1** have connection with

> b1,b2,c1,d1,d2,d3,z1,z2,z3

or node **c1** have connection with

> a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,d1,d2,d3,z1,z2,z3

The posibble path could be :

> a1 -> b1 -> c1 -> d1 -> z1, or c1 -> z2 -> a3 -> b1 -> d2

The distance between every nodes  (except nodes in set, there is no connection ) could be from 0 to 1.

Comment: You've tagged with Dijkstra so you already have an idea? What have you coded so far?

Comment: Sounds like Traveling Salesman problem.

Comment: should be at least as hard as tsp unless the number of sets is  constrained by a function at max logarithmic in the number `n` of nodes. imagine that some oracle would let you know _in advance_ which node to choose from each set. for each set drop all other nodes. your problem has become a tsp instance. nb: if your original problem allows for multiple visits to the same set, it will not be reflected in the said tsp problem while it will make your search even more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the Generalised Travelling Salesman Problem.

From [C. Noon & J.Bean, *An Efficient Transformation of the Generalized Traveling Salesman Problem*](http://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/6834/ban3102.0001.001.pdf;jsessionid=FE47BED6BEFA1D7A88661CBCABEF64AC?sequence=5):

> The *Generalized Traveling Salesman Problem* (GTSP) is a useful model for problems involving decisions of selection and sequence. The asymmetric version of the problem is defined on a directed graph with nodes N, connecting arcs A and a vector of corresponding arc costs c. The nodes are pregrouped into m mutually exclusive and exhaustive nodesets. Connecting arcs are defined only between nodes belonging to different sets, that is, there are no intraset arcs. Each defined arc has a corresponding non-negative cost. The GTSP can be stated as the problem of finding a minimum cost m-arc cycle which includes exactly one node from each nodeset.

This paper explains how to transform your problem to a case of the standard Travelling Salesman Problem.